After installing Python 3.12.3, it fails to create a venv
I just installed the new version of Python.
It installed correctly:
C:\Development\pythontest>python --version
Python 3.12.3

When I try to create the new venv it fails:
C:\Development\pythontest>python -m venv myvenv
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

I have an older version (3.9) on my machine that works fine.  Not sure what's up with this.  As you can see by the first command I changed the path so I know it's calling the version for 3.12.3.
Works:
C:\Users\linda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv myenv

Doesn't work:
C:\Users\linda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -m venv myenv

Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

The same thing happens via PyCharm:

I tried to do an upgrade on an venv with Python 3.9:
C:\Development\pythonsucks>python -m myenv --upgrade m2
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

Python launcher:
C:\Development\pythonsucks>"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" -m venv myenv
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

C:\Development\pythonsucks>py --version
Python 3.12.3

C:\Development\pythonsucks>py -0p
 -V:3.12 *        C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe
 -V:3.9           C:\Users\linda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

C:\Development\pythonsucks>py -m venv test
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib._abc'

I'm  starting to think something is broken in 3.12.

Well, This is working fine in Mac.

Have you tried reinstalling Python?

I have tried repairing it and reinstalling it.  No change.   The only version that works is 3.9

by any chance. do you have PYTHONPATH env variable defined ?

I have PYTHONHOME

PYTHONHOME will affect where standard library is loaded from and if it points to wrong version, it could probably be the culprint of your issue

yup you got it.  want to answer the question I will accept it.

If you have PYTHONHOME pointing to another python interpreter's path, that path from the environment is used to locate standard libraries. With mismatching api's, possible additions and deprecations, issue you described can and will happen.
Suggestions, make sure PYTHONHOME is set correctly or unset it.

i deleted it :) IIR it was required by DaVinci resolve to access the backend api.   i was testing it ages ago and forgot all about it.
